# Windows Phone 7.5 / 8 push notifications and PhoneGap

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, push

we developed a mobile application with PhoneGap. So far it runs fine with WinPhone, iOS, Android and Firefox OS. 
We now want to add Push notifications to the app. Basically we can choose which server backend to use. Since the project is already JS-heavy (ember.js) we started with Node.js and are using node-apn and node-gcm to send notifications to iOS and Android.

Is it even possible to have a PhoneGap application register with the MPNS? So far it seems to me that only native C# Applications can register with their server as a valid endpoint (the node.js plugin for MPNS requires this endpoint to send notifications).
It seems Pushwoosh's phonegap plugin works for windows phone, but only with their service. Or did I misread something there?

The reason we wanted to have a self controlled notification server is to push notifications to Firefox OS. None of the push-services seem to support this OS yet.

Any thoughts on this topic are welcome, thx in advance.

Cheers

Tom

Comment: This plugin should be officially supported, but only for Android and iPhone: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/wiki
However, they say nothing about WP in their doc. If all else fails, you could try to simply write your code in native WP code (C#), I mean, logically it's easy to separate from the rest of your code, since push notification only open your app, but have no further interactions. Also, I'll try to contact above devs and ask, if they have any WP plans...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**Cordova Push Notifications Plugin**](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) added support for Windows Phone 8 recently.

With this plugin, you can now receive and handle Push Notifications on **Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8** devices conveniently.

Comment: We ended up using Pushwoosh anyway, since they have a very good backend, that customers can use to send notifications to test devices or to all devices. But good to know that there is now support for for the WP8 platform in the plugin!

Comment: @Mobiletainment, please could you reply to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042339/windowsphone-phonegap-pushnotification-cannot-get-uri-after-register-my-devi

Comment: ... and has now been conveniently DEPRECATED. The new plugin rejects MPNS notifications.