# WindowsPhone - Phonegap PushNotification - cannot get URI after register my device

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am using [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#automatic_installation) in my cordova/phonegap application for wp8.

I automatically installed the plugin with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

registered it when my device is ready

```
function registerMPNS() {
    console.log("registerMPNS");
    var pushNotification;
    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.register(
    channelHandler,
    errorHandler,
    {
        "channelName": "myChannelTm123",  
        "ecb": "onNotificationWP8",    
        "uccb": "channelHandler", 
        "errcb": "jsonErrorHandler"
    });
}
```

Waiting in **channelHandler** to get my URI which will then be passed to my server

```
function channelHandler(event) {
    console.log("channelHandler ...");
    var uri = event.uri;
    console.log("uri: " + uri);
}
```

//handle MPNS notifications for WP8
    function onNotificationWP8(e) {
        ...
    }

```
function jsonErrorHandler(e) {
    ...
}
```

This is my output console:

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Adding feature.value=Device
Adding feature.value=PushPlugin
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
Updating IsolatedStorage for APP:DeviceID :: a8789b65-b6a7-4ce4-939b-9df90a3edef1
CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted
Apache Cordova native platform version 3.6.3 is starting
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
The thread 0x8d4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
onDeviceReady
 Win32NT 
Received Event: deviceready
platform: Win32NT
registerMPNS
The thread 0xfc4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

The problem is that I am never entering in **channelHandler**, 
Am I missing anything or misunderstood its usage?
I am not asking for the C# code.
I am using one cordova plugin instead and asked help for it.

Comment: @What is your console log is saying? After registerMPNS message, is there anything else?

Comment: @AtillaOzgur, I added it to my question (there is nothing after registerMPNS)

Comment: @JayaVishwakarma, I ended up creating a plugin for push notification, it is very easy. I followed this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx. I also tried https://www.pushwoosh.com/ which is working as well.

Comment: @eeadev can you share the details of how you fixed it? I am also in the same boat. If you can share the plugin it will be highly appreciated

Comment: @pooran, sorry but I cannot share the plugin as It's my company's property now; believe me when I say that would be very easy to do that following this guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx and wrapping a function in a cordova plugin.

Comment: No problem @eeadev, I can understand. outline of fix if you can share at the least would help